# Using string.format with doubles converted to string

Tags: java, string, netbeans, formatting

So I am at somewhat of a loss here. I am trying to format my strings to be only 2 decimal places. I know what you are thinking and I have to have them as strings in order to append them to my JTextArea (these are a small part of my arrayList). So I have converted the doubles into strings using String.valueof() which works fine, however I need to format them in order to print out the string with 2 decimal places. My delcarations and such are as follows

```
class inventoryItem { //Delcare variables below

String itemName;
String newUnit;
String newFee;
String newValue;
String newInventoryValue;
int itemNumber;
int inStock;
double unitPrice;
double value;
double restockingFee;

double inventoryValue;

public inventoryItem(String itemName, int itemNumber, int inStock, double unitPrice) { //declare variables for this class
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
    this.inStock = inStock;
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    restockingFee = .05 * value;
    stockValue();

}

public void stockValue() {
    value = unitPrice * inStock;
    restockingFee = .05 * unitPrice;
    inventoryValue = restockingFee + value;
    newUnit = String.valueOf((double) unitPrice);
    newFee = String.valueOf((double) restockingFee);
    newValue = String.valueOf((double) value);
    newInventoryValue = String.valueOf(inventoryValue);
```

I have tried to do something like

`outputText.append("something = $" + (String.format("%.2f, newUnit))`

but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a way that I can do it while using String.valueOf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

**Sample:**

```
double unitPrice = 1.23235;
java.text.DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new java.text.DecimalFormat( "#,###,###,##0.##" );
String formattedUnitPrice = decimalFormat.format(unitPrice);
```

Output is going to be 1.23

Comment: So are you saying to do this at the point of printing it out, or prior to using the String.valueof()? The reason I ask is because it has to be converted to string prior to printing it out.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying, you should better format your value with a pre defined Decimalformat. Try to google DecimalFormat. That's what you need.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, however I had to modify this slightly to get it to work. I ended up importing DecimalFormat and then creating a new format somewhat like you said above. However in order to get it to print out correctly I had to do something like 'formatted.format(unitPrice)' and it worked like a charm.